# saving a song with sound effect selected by the user in android

Tags: android, soundpool, audio-player, android-music-player

In the default android music player, we can add effects to the song being played like wide concert hall, music clarity etc. and can play the song with respective effects. Is there any way we can save the song with the given effects selected by the user so that the original song gets converted into an entirely new song file with music effects...any help will be deeply appreciated?

P.S. My main motive is to let user add effects to the original song and then save it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with the MediaPlayer class, as it does not allow you to work at a byte level.  I think you want to look into using AudioTracks.  It also has an attachAuxEffect method. Here is the class documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html.  Here is another discussion about this, which might be very useful: [Sample code for Android AudioTrack Mixing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106603/sample-code-for-android-audiotrack-mixing).